# java.lang.SecurityException: intent has extas while passing to other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

**I receive error in S4 but not in any  other device**

please help me to figure out error

My Logcat

```
    12-16 17:44:14.296: E/InputEventReceiver(18735): Exception dispatching input event.
12-16 17:44:14.296: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735): java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent { cmp=com.example.application/.TextAdd (has extras) }
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1674)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at com.example.application.FilterImage.onTouch(FilterImage.java:563)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7812)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1612)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2494)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2274)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8025)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4659)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4547)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4148)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4252)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4175)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4309)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4148)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4175)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4148)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6293)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6202)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6373)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
12-16 17:44:14.326: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18735):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MY Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.application"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FilterImage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:exported="true"
          >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TextAdd"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Crope"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FreeHandDraw"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Contrst"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

used in class

```
stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


            intent = new Intent(FilterImage.this, TextAdd.class);
            intent.putExtra("imagePath", byteArray);
            startActivityForResult(intent,4);
```

onActivityResult

```
 case 4:

            Log.i("Case 4", "called");

            byteArrayReturn =imageReturnedIntent.getByteArrayExtra("ImageTextADD");
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayReturn, 0, byteArrayReturn.length);
            bitmap=bmp;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            break;
```

my line of error is

```
            startActivityForResult(intent,4);
```

Comment: do you have updates on your issue? anything on how to fix it? We've been receiving similar crash reports from time to time

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line:

```
android:exported="true"
```

If you still want to export the activity so that other app components can access it, you must provide intent filters under TextAdd activity declaration.

Comment: removed ....it does not work....why it only have problem in S4 and not in any other device

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of:

```
android:exported="true"
```

from manifest under `TextAdd` activity declaration